# Using MySQLProxy with Sphinx

Tags: sphinx, mysql-proxy

Is there relatively easy way to insert into Sphinx distributed index using MySQL proxy?

E.g. you connect to MySQL proxy and send something like:

> insert into my_ft_index values(1000, 'harry potter');

then MySQLProxy somehow calculate the hash of 1000 and decide where to forward this insert?

Answer (score 1):

See:
http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=13632

From what I understand there, mysqlproxy wouldnt work (but havent tried)

Frankly its pretty trival to implemnent in application code. (ie 'picking' which server to send the request) - if was a HA setup, with multiple servers per shard, less so.

Comment: very helpful. I did not know about load balancer setup.